# Installing install-info

Tags: software-installation, gnu

I do not have root  privileges in my system and I have noticed that I don't have access to a `install-info` binary, even though I need to install an Emacs package (CEDET).

In the past, whenever I had to use a binary not provided by the system admin, I downloaded it to my home directory and installed it there for my personal use.

I would like to do the same thing with `install-info` (i.e. install it under my home directory) but I don't know where  to download it from.  How can I get `install-info` and install it in my home directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`install-info` is part of GNU texinfo, which you can get from http://www.gnu.org/software/texinfo/